# Using lodash in Angular 4

Tags: angular, lodash

I have previously used lodash in my Angular 4 application by simply importing it and using it as shown here:

```
import lodash from 'lodash';

public getSubtotal() : number {
  return lodash.sumBy(this.cartItems, function(item) {        
    return item.product.price * item.item.quantity;
  })
```

}

I am once again trying to use lodash similarly but am getting an error that lodash is undefined.

```
import lodash from 'lodash';

lodash.indexOf([1, 2, 1, 2], 2);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at CustomizeComponent.showTopping (customize.component.ts:39)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CustomizeComponent.html:285)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14638)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13785)
at callViewAction (core.js:14136)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14068)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13791)
at callViewAction (core.js:14136)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14094)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13786)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First you need to install the packages [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) and [@types/lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash) (contains type definitions):

```
npm i lodash
npm i --save-dev @types/lodash
```

Then you can use lodash e.g. with `import * as _ from 'lodash';` and further do `_.indexOf([1, 2, 1, 2], 2);`

You could also do `import * as _isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';` (thanks to joshrathke) or `import {isEmpty} from 'lodash';`

Comment: For what its worth directly importing only the modules you need can make your build significantly smaller. Signifigantly, relative to the Lodash library :)

`import * as _indexOf from 'lodash/indexOf';

Comment: @joshrathke That's a good point. I will edit my answer to add this point.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @pzaenger `import * as _isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';` does not work. Says `This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript...`

Comment: @Rich - Give this a try instead - import { isEmpty as _isEmpty } from 'lodash'

Comment: Building on both the import style suggested by @joshrathke and the bracket syntax in the answer, my favorite method is `import { isEmpty as _isEmpty, cloneDeep as _cloneDeep } from 'lodash';`  It's the best of both worlds.  You can rename the lodash modules and you don't need knowledge of the internal structure of lodash.  I showed multiple lodash modules for good measure :-). Edit: just saw @thiag0 answer, which is the same thing lol.  Well this at least shows importing multiple modules ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯